# Timeshift a series in Grafana with an InfluxDB database

Tags: grafana, influxdb, home-assistant, timeshift

I have an InfluxDB 4.5.0 database running on Home assistant 2022.8.7.
I want to plot two InfluxDB queries on the same Grafana 7.6.0 graph, but one series is timeshifted by +24hrs.

After several hours of research I see it it possible to timeshift all the series on a Grafana panel using the "Query Options" but I can find no way to timeshift just one of the series.

I note that there is a timeshift function in InfluxDB but am stumped as to how I can modify the query in Grafana to timeshift this by +24hrs

As an example, if the series I want to timeshift is given by the query

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM "kWh" WHERE ("entity_id" = 'energy_tomorrow') AND time >= now() - 7d and time <= now() GROUP BY time(5m) fill(linear)
```

is there anyway to modify this query to timeshift the result by +24h, or alternatively what other method is available to achieve this basic result in Grafana with InfluxDB ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After many hours of trying I've finally found a solution, and post for any others with the same problem.
There are two ways of connecting influxDB to Grafana on home assistant

1. InfluxQL : which is an SQL like query language and the default connection method
2. Flux : which is InfluxData’s functional data scripting language

It does not seem possible to timeshift with (1), but there is a function in (2) which allows timeshifting. So the solution is to add a new *datasource* in grafana, through the UI

```
Configuration : Data Sources : Add Data Source : InfluxDB
```

Give this new *datasource* a recognisable name (eg FluxQuery) and configure this *datasource* to use Flux instead of the default InfluxQL. Then when adding a new panel in grafana, providing you select the appropriate *datasource* (eg FluxQuery), then flux querying is enabled and timeshifting possible.

As an example, if the InfluxDB database has the name *HomeAssistant* which includes two database *entity_id*'s called *energy_today* and *energy_tomorrow*. The following flux query plots *energy_today* timeshfited +24hrs so it overlays correctly on *energy_tomorrow*

Query A

```
from(bucket: "HomeAssistant/autogen")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "kWh")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "energy_tomorrow")
```

Query B

```
from(bucket: "HomeAssistant/autogen")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> timeShift(duration: 24h)                    
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "kWh")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "energy_today")
```